# How to use rtsp://video/sample.mp4 in HTML5 ?

Tags: html, rtsp

I want to use  rtsp://videos/sample.mp4 as HTML5 video tag 'src' attribute. I used it as below,

```
<video  width="560" height="314" id="video1"  src="rtsp://videos/sample.mp4">
       The browser does not support HTML5
</video>
```

but it is not working in any browser. It want to be work in both safari and chrome. How i can do this ?

or any other way to use the url as http://videos//sample.mp4 .

Any settings in server or client side.?

Comment: Start by using the right syntax: `rtsp://videos/sample.mp4`

Comment: hi deceze ,  
it is a typo, by mistake

Answer (score -1):

Try separating source from video tag.

```
<video  width="560" height="314" id="video1">
  <source src="rtsp://videos/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```